# makeText error in Android exersize

Tags: android

I am new to Android and trying to do an excersize from a book, but I keep getting an error saying that makeText is not allowed, but it is as far as I can see exactly as in the book.
Does anyone have an idea whats wrong here?

```
package com.madebyjohann.contentproviders;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button queryButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        queryButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                queryContact ();
            }

            private void queryContact() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Cursor nameCursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
                while (nameCursor.moveToNext()) {
                    String contactName =
                            nameCursor.getString(nameCursor
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY));
                                    Toast.makeText(this, contactName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                nameCursor.close();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly what you should have done.  In your Toast line:

```
Toast.makeText(this, contactName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

the "this" refers to the inner-most class, i.e. the OnClickListener that you're building.

Whenever you have "new Something()", that means you are instantiating a class.  Always, using "this" in a class will refer to that instance - the inner-most class.

An OnClickListener() class is not a Context, which is why your makeText() was failing.  That first parameter needs to be a Context, and since the Activity class extends a Context (`public class MainActivity extends Activity`), you can add `MainActivity.this` here and it will be valid.

Comment: I am just surprised they made this mistake in the training book I am using :(
Again, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the following, and it seems to have worked, but not sure if this is what I should have done??

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, contactName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

MakeText only builds the object. You need to call show on the resulting object.